# Remove the first blank line from every document Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I use markdown with YAML frontmatter as below. I want to remove the first blank line that appears in every document using Notepad++. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to do this. Thanks in advance. Examples below

```
---
title: My Title

slug: /slug/
---
```

```
---
title: My Title
category: cat

slug: /slug/
---
```

Edit: Some paragraphs end with `--` in markdown, so those should not be targeted. only the `---` should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `---(?:(?!---).)+?\K(\R){2,}`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
---             # literally 3 dashes
        # Tempered Greedy Token
(?:             # non capture group
    (?!---)         # negative lookahead, make sure we have not 3 dashes
    .               # any character
)+?             # end group may appear 1 or more times, not greedy
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(\R){2,}        # group 1, any kind of linebreak, must occur 2 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, a linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works but with a small caveat. I have some posts with sentences ending with `--` before a list, a blank line, then the list. The code removes that blank line too. Is that an expected behaviour?

Comment: @user18336975: Please, edit your question and add more test cases. Have a try with `(?=.*?---)` at the end of the regex, so it becomes `---(?:(?!---).)+?\K(\R){2,}(?=.*?---)`

Comment: This worked! I appreciate your assistance.